# Aliens disguised as school children learn about humans in retro TV show

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I want to find out what this is, I think its a book adapted TV series for children (around the 90s) There are green furry aliens with tenticles (that looks vaguely like the plant monster from little shop of horrors) They wear costumes of school children and teachers (i think red blazers and freaky doll masks) They go out into the world and observe humans doing things.. 
Thats all i remember although I have a sketch also!
[image: Alien Schoolchild]

Comment: Any help finding this will be great!

Comment: Loving the sketch. Precisely how were they *disguised* though?

Comment: Was this a 'schools program' of some sort?

Comment: Now *this* is effort! :) +1. I think you're after [Dr. Xargle](http://d.gr-assets.com/books/1387736425l/1145666.jpg), BTW, there was a [show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Xargle#Television_series) based on it back in 1997 with alien teacher and students (it's pretty obscure, though).

Comment: Absolutely Magnificent! It was the live action one I was remembering but i knew id seen it drawn before!
Thanks alot!

Comment: They're both the same show, BTW, it contained both animation and puppets. (Er, unless you already knew that and I misunderstood)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like [Dr. Xargle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Xargle#Television_series) from 1997, based on the [children's book series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Xargle). From an [online synopsis](http://www.bcdb.com/cartoon-story/71816-Earthlets):

> Dr. Xargle, supposedly Planet Queeg's greatest expert on life on Planet Earth, is trying to teach his class of unruly Queegles about "Earthlets". He takes the class on the first of many field trips to study earth life at first hand.

It's pretty obscure (I can't even find it on IMDb), but the intro is online and you can see that the aliens look very much your sketch:

Comment: Thanks! I remember the cartoon now, it was the live-action one with puppets (their masks looked like angry kid-style doll faces, very freaky) that i was remembering, my memory of their design isnt far off! should have remembered the multiple eyes and glasses though!

Comment: I found some pictures of the freaky disguises, the puppets (and puppeteers), and some more info at Richard Coombes' website! [![child disguises](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KQ80K.jpg)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KQ80K.jpg) [Dr.Xargle Puppets](http://www.richardcoombs.co.uk/drxargle.htm)